# Which op-amp should I use to measure voltage across a current sense resistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, current-measurement, differential

I want to implement current sensing functionality on an MCU (STM32F103 bluepill), but in order to read voltages across the shunts, I would need a differential amplifier to eliminate noise first before administering that signal to the ADCs.

I am completly stumped as to which op-amp I should pick for the job however, especially since I couldn't find readily available differential amplifiers in my regional stores' online catalogue. That being said, would a comparator be a better option than a regular op-amp? I've heard that the LM358 is a popular general purpose op-amp nowadays. I've also heard that I would need a single supply op-amp, which confuses me quite a bit since I haven't seen the term before in op-amp datasheets and TI states that all op-amps can be used with a single-supply in [this application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf) (page seven, second paragraph).

(Ignore part numbers on this schematic since my local electronics' shops do not have them. I would like to get recommendations on other well-known op-amps that are widely available, preferable low power ones.)

[image: Ignore part numbers]

specs:
Vcc=3.3 V, Vss=0 V
current: 27 mA-1 A
shunt resistance: 0.01 Ω.

Comment: An alternative is a current shunt amplifier made specifically for the task: https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/current-sense/overview.html?keyMatch=CURRENT%20SENSE%20AMPLIFIERS

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking because you have the answer, right in your question.  Forget using an opamp and rolling your own differential circuit, just use a chip specifically designed to do that for you.  The INA181 in your schematic, much like other chips such as the TCS888, is meant to detect the drop on shunt and generate a signal ready to be fed into the A/D.  Compute the shunt value based on your requirements and you are done.

Comment: You don't need a voltage divider. The circuit in your drawing measures the low-side current, so the INA will not see harmful voltages. Just choose a suitable shunt and supply the INA with 3.3V.

Comment: Where do 12V actually come into play? The INA181 is rated for 6V max and you should power it from the same rail as the STM32/ADC.

Comment: @Yiannis it seems that i -accidentally- omitted the part where i addressed this in the post, that op amp isn't available for in my region, therefore i am asking if any famous op amps are used for such purposes that i might find in a local electronics shop ( buying online or abroad isn't an option due to certain circumstances).

Comment: @A.H.Z You can request a few free samples from TI or order them from the TI website and they will ship almost anywhere in the world. (Unless there are trade restrictions in your country.)

Comment: @A.H.Z, if the issue is you can only get certain parts but not others, you will have to fully specify which parts you can get and which you can't.  The differential amplifier topology is more or less the same (you can look it up online in numerous places) but the devil is in the details so you will have to do some work.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar question.
That's what I realized:
The operational amplifier can be with a different type of power supply: unipolar (for example: +12V and ground) or bipolar (for example: +5V and -5V). Only a single-pole power supply system is suitable for current measurement. On the shunt, you usually measure a voltage drop of 80 mV. And the LM358 has an offset of 2 mV (which is 2.5%). therefore, you should use another operational amplifier such as the AD8630 (Offset Voltage (VOS), 0.001 mV). Offset Voltage and Offset Voltage Drift - affect the accuracy of measurements, which is why it is better to use an operational amplifier with Zero drift.

Answer (score 1):

Analog Devices has precision op-amps with ‘over the rail’ capability that can be used to sense current on the high side. This is much more convenient as you don’t have to break into the load's ground connection. If your load has other I/O going to it this helps a lot.

More here: https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/current-sense-amplifiers.html

I personally have used the [LTC6102](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6102.html#product-overview) for sensing a 12V load with good results. It has a ±10μV offset (much better than what you can get with an LM358), allowing you to use more gain and a smaller sense resistor.

This part is different from a normal op-amp: it uses a current-source output, making it easy to scale the signal to best use your ADC input range.